# Text encryption/decryption methods Java

Tags: android, encryption, des

I am working on Android project where I have to use both encryption and decryption methods. scenario as below:

1. User type password in SignupActivity
2. user's password is encrypted
3. in Login Activity password is retrieved from data base and decrypt method is called

my problem  is in step 3 it always return null from decryption.

Code sample:

SignUpActivity:

```
    String name_data = name.getText().toString();
    String email_data = email.getText().toString();
    String password_data = password.getText().toString();

    password_data = enc.getEncryptedText(password_data);
```

LoginActivity

```
            String password_in_database = helper.searchPassword(email_data);
            password_in_database = enc.getDecryptedText(password_in_database);
```

Encryption/Decryption class

```
public class EncryptDecryptStringWithDES {

    public static Cipher ecipher;
    public static Cipher dcipher;

    public static SecretKey key;


    public static String getEncryptedText(String sty) throws Exception {

        // generate secret key using DES algorithm
        key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");


        // initialize the ciphers with the given key

        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);




        sty = encrypt(sty);

        return sty;
    }

    public static String getDecryptedText(String sty) throws Exception {
   key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        sty = decrypt(sty);

        return sty;

    }


    public static String encrypt(String str) {

        try {

            // encode the string into a sequence of bytes using the named charset

            // storing the result into a new byte array.

            byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

            byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

// encode to base64

            enc = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(enc);

            return new String(enc);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }

    public static String decrypt(String str) {

        try {

            // decode with base64 to get bytes

            byte[] dec = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(str.getBytes());

            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

// create new string based on the specified charset

            return new String(utf8, "UTF8");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: My project is a passwords manager application , saves user passwords and list all the passwords at same time. that why I need to encrypt and decrypt.

I think the problem is it always generate different key for both methods

Comment: Debug: hex dump the keys. How will you securely save the encryption key? Do not use DES, it is no longer considered safe, use AES.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use DES, use AES.

The best you can do is not saving the password. Instead, use the password as the key to AES. That's means your user will have to type in the password on each boot, but it's the most secure solution.

If you have to save the password locally, you need a consistent key - your code generate a new key each function call. Generate a new key on signup and store it encrypted with a fixed key on shared preferences.